# SQL Server - View or Stored Proc to Union All On a Growing Table List

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

The SQL server has tables that all have the same structure. tableX_2016, tableX_2017, tableX_2018, tableX_2019, tableX_2020, tableX_2021.

I want a view that is simply:

```
select * from tableX_2016 
union all select * from tableX_2017
union all select * from tableX_2018
union all select * from tableX_2019
union all select * from tableX_2020
union all select * from tableX_2021
```

However, I would like that view to automatically pick up tableX_2022, tableX_2023, etc., once they exist.  The best would be to put all this data in one table (!), but unfortunately, I do not have the latitude to do that.

Is there a way to do this in a view?  Or, a way to do it in a stored procedure and then somehow consume that stored procedure as if it were a view (use its output in CTEs, join to its output, etc)?

Thanks!

Comment: _this in a view_ Not directly - a view cannot contain dynamic sql. A procedure could be used the resultset but you cannot join to it like a view. You could create/alter a view whenever a new table is created. However, this is logic that needs to be done ONCE EVER YEAR. Exactly how much effort are you saving by trying to automate a solution?

Comment: Right, it needs to be done once a year.  There are about 10 sets of tables like the one I mentioned, I just prefer not to have annual processes to remember and execute (and I might not be there at some point and maybe end users can't figure it out [edit: I am an end user myself, this is what you might call 'shadow IT work']).  My hope was that there was an 'easy way' to handle this and it was just outside of my knowledge base.... there are daily jobs running on this server; I suppose I *could* add stored procs there that drop and re-write the ~10 views for example.

Comment: Perhaps schedule a monthly or yearly job to dynamically update the view?  We have something similar, but not for a view.  Ours is required yearly, but I have test runs monthly and just prior to the real run.  It does a rollback on data changes.  We get an alert if it fails.  The tables should be the same...until they are not.

Comment: Whenever I see table names that contain the date it is almost always a bad design. A date column in the table is almost always a much better idea than creating all these tables.

Comment: @Sean, agree.  It is a dumb setup.  An undoubtedly lots of processes have been built around it that are being updated yearly by lots of unknown users.  A date column even exists *in all but the current-year table, which also doesn't have the year in its name*... Most of the date fields in this server's tables are stored as varchar, too.  Unfortunately I can't change these things.

Comment: The only way to do this dynamically is with dynamic sql. That rules out making a view. But you could do this with a stored procedure although it would be ugly and scary.

Comment: A job can create update a test view and include a few tests.  When it's really time, then it could update the production view.  I understand the pain as one of our apps used separate tables and unions for some commonly used data - nested complex views everywhere.

Comment: I suppose you could create a job or a stored procedure that would use dynamic sql to update your view once a year. I understand your dilemma about not being able to fix the problem but at some point that design is going to have to get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Database design seems poor. If you are keeping data in same database, it would be wise to handle by creating year or date column.

However, you can achieve your result by the given query

```sql
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##temp
    SELECT * INTO ##temp FROM dbo.tableX_2016
    TRUNCATE TABLE ##temp
    
    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable
    @command1 = 'INSERT INTO ##temp SELECT * FROM ?',
    @whereand = 'AND OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) LIKE ''tableX_%'''
    
    SELECT * FROM ##temp
```

Note that, `sp_MSforeachtable` is an undocumented stored procedure in SQL Server

PS: You can create view, stored procedure, etc. as per the need using above query